# Windows batch function gets called an extra time

Tags: windows, function, batch-file, javac, goto

I have a batch script that compiles and runs a Java program and as it is doing this it prints a timestamp of when the task started. I noticed that the `:printDate` function is being called an additional time at the very end, but `:exit` should end the script after "Done..." is printed.

```sh
@echo off

set PRGM=Foo
cls

call :printDate
echo Compiling...
javac %PRGM%.java

call :printDate
echo Executing...
java %PRGM%

call :printDate
echo Results...
type output.txt

call :exit

:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:: Functions
:: ----------------------------------------------------------

:printDate
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %DATE%') do (set mydate=%%c/%%a/%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:./ " %%a in ('echo %TIME%') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b:%%c)
echo|set /p=[%mydate% %mytime%] 
goto:eof

:exit
call:printDate
echo Done...
goto:eof
```

Here is my output

```
[2013/10/17 21:26:11] Compiling...
[2013/10/17 21:26:12] Executing...
[2013/10/17 21:26:12] Results...
2
6
6
5
[2013/10/17 21:26:12] Done...
[2013/10/17 21:26:12]
```

---

**Edit**

If anyone is interested, here is my working script: http://pastebin.com/xfwStvNK. My Java program generates the output file and the script generates the input and prints the output after compiling and running the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:printDate` procedure is called another time because you don't finish the execution when calling the `:exit` procedure, you are calling the `:printDate` inside the `:exit` procedure but after the `echo Done` you are returning to the `call :exit` line so `:printDate` block is processed one more time then really the `goto:eof` line inside the `:printDate` is the real end of the script.

That is the meanning of a `Call`, Instead you need to use the `GoTo` keyword, like this:

```
...
REM call :exit
Goto :Exit
...

...
:exit
call:printDate
echo Done...
REM goto:eof
Exit
```

Comment: So I just specified a label at the very end of the program called `:Exit` because I do not want the script to kill the command line. This works, great thanks. Here is my updated script: http://pastebin.com/xfwStvNK

Comment: Is there a better; more efficient way to return from functions than `goto:eof`?

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl not, but why are you trying to mean with "better; more efficient"?, Going to EndOfFile is the only way and better efficient while Batch it's a "batch processing" language. Please feel free to mark this answer as 'accepted' If the code has resolved your question, thanks for read and forgive my English.

Comment: I will do some more research. Thanks for the answer, it helped me understand what was happening.

Comment: Found my answer here: [goto](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/goto.php) - *"In NT, a call to a subroutine's label (CALL :label), combined with GOTO :EOF to terminate the subroutine, presents a way to create real subroutines, GOTO :EOF being the instruction to jump back to where the subroutine was called."* This is the best option based on this blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Always use **Goto** label to terminate your *main* program.

Example:

```html
echo hello world<br>
call:doFirstThing<br>
call:doSecondThing<br>
<p>
Goto :FinalExit<br>
<p>
:doFirstThing<br>
echo in the first method<br>
goto:eof<br>
<p>
:doSecondThing<br>
echo in the second method<br>
goto:eof<br>
<p>
FinalExit<br>
```